# AngularJS site only working when launching through IIS

Tags: angularjs, iis, fullpage.js

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 to build HTML-Pages as I like the editor. Today I am working on a page which generates its content with AngularJS and is being formatted by Fullpage.js
Now I am trying to debug my page. When I am launching it with F5 on Visual Studio, Angular works as it should and creates all data I want it to create, but fullpage.js does not work (no console errors, just not doing anything at all).
If I am opening the html file manually in my browser, the exact opposite happens: Angular does not work (I tracked it down to the part of my code where I fill my $scope via $http.get() to a local json file), but fullpage.js seems to work fine, just without content.

I imported fullpage, angular and jquery through the nuget packet manager, might that be the issue or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know about angular, but check out [this repo](https://github.com/hellsan631/angular-fullpage.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to deploy your code to a different server instead of opening it up in your browser? This sounds like a CORS problem.

Comment: Gonna try that now, sounds like what could be the issue

Comment: nope, angular won't run. can that be an issue with the `$http.get()`?

Comment: What are your console errors when you deploy it to a different server? And if you don't see any console errors, look in the `Resources` tab in the developer tools/window and see if the `.js` files are even loading or being recognized.

Comment: Getting no console errors, I have converted my json file to a js object manually now and it works, so there is an issue with the http requests.

Comment: Accepted this answer as it basically is correct: The HTTP Request won't work without a webserver, therefore loading the content with angular does not happen.